# Why difference in FlagStatus between set done in task view or inbox of Outlook Application (VSTO Addin)

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, office-interop

I have a MailItem with a reminder.
There are 2 (unfortunately separate) ways to set it done.

```
1st in tasks folder (so the item will be removed there).

2nd in inbox folder (item stand still there with green hook)
```

Now my problem:

If I check the field **FlagStatus** over interop in my `c#` application, the status does not change after 1st method! Only, if I set it done in inbox folder, I get a new status in `c#.`

Does anyone know why?

Are there another way in code to check the "Task-Status" of MailItem?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking: are you asking why creating a separate TaskItem in the Tasks fodder does not update any task related properties on a separate  email message in some other folder? Why would it?

Comment: No. I mean only MailItems with active Reminder in it. So you see this mail item in task view of outlook like a task item.
But my question is about setting done.